# SQLite error handling with JavaScript and ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, sqlite, express

I created a Backend route to fetch games with specific provided letters. Below you can find two routes i created:

```
router.get("/public/gamelist/:letter", (req, res, next) => {
  var sql = "SELECT title FROM Games WHERE title LIKE ? || '%' AND ownage = 'true'"
  var params = [req.params.letter]
  db.all(sql, params, (err, rows) => {
    if (rows) {
      return res.status(200).json(rows);
    } else if (!rows) {
      return res.json({ "answer": "NoGame" })
    } else if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({ "error": err.message });
      return;
    }
  });
});

router.get("/public/game/:title", (req, res, next) => {
  var sql = "select * from Games where title = ?"
  var params = [req.params.title]
  db.get(sql, params, (err, row) => {
    if (row) {
      res.status(200).json(row);
    } else if (!row) {
      console.log("Dont exist")
      return res.json({ "answer": "NoGame" })
    } else if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({ "error": err.message });
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

the second route `/public/game/:title` works as expected, while the first one `/public/gamelist/:letter` doesn´t catch the empty result. It always returns `200`, when no game exists it simply returns an empty array instead of `({ "answer": "NoGame" })`

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with this part of my code?

Comment: Probably your query has a mistake. Open SQLite CLI or DB Browser for SQLite and first run your query through there, replace ? with any value you try to attach to the query, and see if you get any results

Answer (score 0):

```
// Happy coding guys
const express=require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')
const app=express()

app.set("view engine","ejs")
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use("/", routes)


app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("SERVER ACTIVE");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static addSongGet(request,response){
        let error=request.query.error
        if (!error) {
            error=[]
        }else{
            error=error.split(',')
        }
        console.log(error);
        ModelSongs.addSongGet((err,data)=>{
            if (err) {
                response.send(err)
            }else{
                // console.log(error);
                response.render("songsAdd",{data,error})
            }
        })
    }
    static addSongPost(request,response){
        // console.log('ini dari control');
        ModelSongs.addSongPost(request,(err,data)=>{
            if (err) {
                // console.log(err);
                response.redirect(`/songs/add?error=${err}`)
            }else{
                response.redirect('/songs')
            }
        })
    }
```